# Microsoft XNA framework redistributable v4.0 Installed but cannot find reference assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna-4.0

I installed the Microsoft XNA framework redistributable 4.0 but I am not able to find any of its assemblies to work with in Visual Studio 2010. My window crashed and I have to get it downloaded from net. Before window crashed it was working fine. Please help me in this issue!

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this only if re-running the installer for xna does not work 
(the file located [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714))

[Steps to install XNA Game Studio 4.0 without using the setup bootstrapper](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/11/05/10086842.aspxRedirected=true)

Additionally I'd recommend you take a look at [MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki) or another xna implementation out in the wild since [Microsoft is no longer supporting XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714091/c-sharp-game-development-after-xna).