# Using WPF for creating desktop games

Tags: c#, wpf

i am new to C# development and i have this doubt

My requirement is to create a Pacman-like game which has simple graphics

Can WPF be used to develop games like this?

Is it "right" to use WPF for creating games or are there better ways to create a simple desktop game using C#?

Comment: The XNA framework is specifically made for that. And then you can deploy it to your XBOX! That said, I don't think WPF is a bad choice, but definitely have a look at XNA.

Comment: WPF wasn't made for games, but it could support better graphics than WinForms, but has terrible framerate control. If you're looking to make a game, check out Xna. Xna is made specifically for gaming, so it's your best option.

Comment: To any future readers, XNA has been discontinued.

Comment: @FizzledOut what to use or a substitute to xna then  ?

Comment: @CustomizedName http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714091/c-sharp-game-development-after-xna

Answer (score 4):

This [**tutorial**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476349/XNA-in-Windows-8-from-dream-to-reality) should help you, WPF is not really optimize for desktop game plus it doesn't have game engine just to name one.