# How to sense if two objects are touching each other in XNA Game Studio?

Tags: c#, xna

I've recently started coding a game in XNA Game Studio using C#, however I am having trouble detecting when a ball hits a particular block, could someone help.

Note: `blocksPosition` is an Array, as there is multiple of them

Here is my code:

```
public Boolean DetectBallBox(int BoxNum)
    {
        if (blocksPosition[BoxNum].X >= ballPosition.X + ball.Width && blocksPosition[BoxNum].Y >= ballPosition.Y + ball.Height)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

public void detectBallCollision()
    {
        for (int blockCount = 0; blockCount < 40; blockCount++)
        {
            if (DetectBallBox(blockCount))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Block Hit");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you suggest something that is better and newerthen xna please?

Comment: Try google. Heres another discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714091/c-sharp-game-development-after-xna

Comment: @steve _"Slightly OT, but XNA is already end of life. "_ - perhaps.  But it is still useful as a learning tool

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**

use Rectangle.Intersects:

```
Rectangle x = new Rectangle(ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height);
Rectangle y = new Rectangle(x,y, width, height);
return x.Intersects(y);
```

Thats really simple answer, becouse ball is more like ellipse... :)

**Better solution**

Finding intersection between Rectangle and Ellipse:

```
System.Drawing.Rectangle brick = new Rectangle();
int ballX, ballY, radiusX, radiusY;

brick.Width = // dont see it in your code
brick.Height = // dont see it in your code
brick.X = blocksPosition[BoxNum].X;
brick.Y = blocksPosition[BoxNum].Y;

ballX = ballPosition.X;
ballY = ballPosition.Y;

radiusX = ball.Width;
radiusY = ball.Height;

// find closest point:
var closestX = Math.Min(brick.Width + brick.X, Math.Max(ballX, brick.X));
var closestY = Math.Min(brick.Height + brick.Height, Math.Max(ballY, brick.Y));

// find distance:
var distanceX = ballX - closestX;
var distanceY = ballY - closestY;

// if distance is lesser then circle radius, then we have intersaction:
var dSq = ((distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY))
if (dSq < (radiusX*radiusX))
{
  return dSq < (radiusY*radiusY);
}
return false;
```

**The Best solution (©®™):**

Use any 2d physics engine, like, lets say [Farseer](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/). Its more to learn from start, but in end, it will be much better and easier for you.

Quick and Dirty example of Ball hitting brick will looks like this:

```
World world = new World(new Vector2(0f, 0f)); // no gravity

Body myBall = world.CreateBody();
myBall.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape(0.5f);
Fixture fixture = myBall.CreateFixture(circleShape);

Fixture brick = FixtureFactory.CreateRectangle();
// etc... Setting Position and so on.
// Its big topic to discuss here whole project.
```

and every frame:

```
world.Step(0.033333f); // 60 fps
```

In final project, you will have two "spaces" - one physical (where you/farseer will count collisions, forces etc) and second one, where you draw your bodies from physic world (btw - Body is only point in space, Shape is any shape / polygon and Fixture is what is holding Body and Shape together... As i say, its really big topic. Feel free to ask any other question about Farseer :) )